# How can I find the ODATA Service URL associated with my Fiori app?

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori, s4hana

I have a series of Fiori apps I want to programatically extract the data from using the pyodata rest api. In order to do this, I need a endpoint URL which is available *somewhere* in SAP. My understand is that every fiori app has an associated odata service which is used to gather data, where can I get the service url for this?

Comment: A fiori application does not necessarily have one OData endpoint, it can also have several.

You should find the name of the OData services in the manifest.json file which contains the fiori application configuration.

More particularly in the property:
sap.app dataSources , that's dataSources of type OData